# Center ListView horizontally

Tags: android, android-listview

As easy as it seems to be, as stubbornly this ListView won't center itself (or it's content within - doesn't matter to me).

This is activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.drobiazko.den.mobineon.MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/bg">

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/clock_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!--<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark">-->

        <com.drobiazko.den.mobineon.ListViewRowsHeight
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
            android:persistentDrawingCache="scrolling|animation"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />
    <!--</RelativeLayout>-->
</LinearLayout>
```

This is ListView's item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/btn_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/custom_btn_icon" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/btn_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/custom_btn_name" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/btn_count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/custom_btn_count" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I've tried everything (including simplifying layout to max), but it still won't go.

Funny that the first relative layout clock_container - centers like a charm, due to parent LinearLayout's `android:gravity="center_horizontal"`. Why won't ListView?

**Added later:**
Inspired by **FOliveira**'s answer, I've done some investigation and found that:
everything works fine, parent `LinearLayout` has `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` and centers his children respectfully. The reason for ListView's children are left-aligned is that ListView takes all possible width despite his `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` attribute.

Anyone knows why is that?

Comment: The `ListView` has `wrap_content` as `layout_height`. Never do that, that defies the purpose of a `ListView` and it won't work properly.

Comment: Not that I doubt your advice, but it works! Maybe because adapter for my ListView is set up to show only 6 items, and allow to scroll for all the rest...

Comment: I realise it's not really related to your problem, but putting `wrap_content` on a `ListViews` height is something you should never do. The `ListView` is not designed for that, just think about it: You have a `ListView` because you want to scroll through a bunch of items which do not fit on the screen. By setting `wrap_content` as `layout_height` you are telling the `ListView` to do the completely opposite, to be as tall as all child views combined. As such having a `ListView` with `wrap_content` will just cause problems in the long run. The same applies to any `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all , i would remove the first linear layout and stay only with the relative layout as the parent.

After having the relative layout as the main parent , set the `CENTER_IN_PARENT` attribute to true.

The mistake you are making is that you are setting the gravity of Linear Layout child to center horizontal, which is correct, but the only children being affected by this option is the Relative layout itself.